# How to set black transparent for UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, cagradientlayer

I would like to set a transparent black background colour for a UILabel.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = label.frame;
[label.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

Can I use a gradient to achieve this? Or should I use some other method? Please help me achieve this effect.

I would like to achieve the below effect:

[image]

Comment: Hey kishore...lets chat again its simple bro

Comment: yeah just now i seen the lot of answer its simple ,but just now i understood bro @VijayPalwe

Comment: thats fine you got the ans right? enjoy happy coding

Comment: yes thankyou @VijayPalwe

Comment: for minus reason please .

Comment: you dont need to use cagradient layer for simple alpha change!!

Comment: @Mr.T That isn't a duplicate of this question. That other question wants a fully clear background. This question does not.

Comment: The title seemed similar to me.As the answers from the two questions shows same solution which is modifyng the alpha value,hence I thought it as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:0.7];
```

What you will adjust is `alpha:0.7`

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `backgroundColor`property of your `UILabel`to a color with an alpha channel different from 1 :

```
label.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
```

Comment: are you sure `[[UIColor blackColor] 0.5]` will work?

Comment: Oops while replacing the value, the whole colorWithAlphaComponent got selected. Nice catch !

Answer (score 1):

set simple like

```
label.opaque = NO;
```

the above choice is not work try

```
   yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.4];
```

Obviously you can change the RGB colors to what you want.

Comment: bro y we have to give label.opaque = NO;

Comment: if you set it will set automatically decrase transparency ...

Comment: KArthik thank you bro